# Remove empty objects from an object using recursion (using vanila ES6 javascript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove **null** & **empty objects** inside an object (but **not falsy values**), with recursively.

I have implemented logic **without recursion** not sure how to **do with recursion**, with deep **nested objects**.

```
const clearNullEmpties = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {}

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, val], i) => {
    const isNotNull = val !== null
    const isObject = isNotNull && val.constructor === Object
    const isEmptyObj = isObject && Object.keys(val).length === 0

    (!isEmptyObj) && Object.assign(newObj, { [k]: val })

  })

  return newObj
}
```

```
// Example Data
let object = {
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: {
            a: 1,
            d: {},
            e: {
              f: {} 
            }
        }
    },
    b: {}
}


let expectedResult = {
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: {
            a: 1,
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have gone throw this answer [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736367/8592918)
but its not follows es6 (i don't want to modify(mutate) original object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively remove nullish values from a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413342/recursively-remove-nullish-values-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: It does job well, but in my case I don't want to remove empty strings or empty arrays like.  ' ', []

Comment: @customcommander  By the way I will going to use only spread, because of your articles **Spread vs Assign (JS)** .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an interesting problem. I think it can be solved elegantly if we write a generic `map` and `filter` function that works on both Arrays *and* Objects -

```js
function map (t, f)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.map(f)
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([k, v]) =>  [k, f(v, k)]))
    default:
      return t
  }
}

function filter (t, f)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.filter(f)
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).filter(([k, v]) =>  f(v, k)))
    default:
      return t
  }
}
```

We can write your `removeEmpties` program easily now -

```js
const empty =
  Symbol("empty") // <- sentinel

function removeEmpties (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
    case Object:
      return filter(map(t, removeEmpties), nonEmpty)
    default:
      return nonEmpty(t) ? t : empty  // <-
  }
}
```

Now we have to define what it means to be `nonEmpty` -

```js
function nonEmpty (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.length > 0
    case Object:
      return Object.keys(t).length > 0
    default:
      return t !== empty // <- all other t are OK, except for sentinel
  }
}
```

Finally we can compute the `result` of your `input` -

```js
const input =
    {a: {b: 1, c: {a: 1, d: {}, e: {f: {}}}}, b: {}}

console.log(removeEmpties(input))
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const empty =
  Symbol("empty")

function removeEmpties (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
    case Object:
      return filter(map(t, removeEmpties), nonEmpty)
    default:
      return nonEmpty(t) ? t : empty
  }
}

function nonEmpty (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.length > 0
    case Object:
      return Object.keys(t).length > 0
  //case String:             // <- define any empty types you want
  //  return t.length > 0
    default:
      return t !== empty // <- all other t are OK, except for sentinel
  }
}

function map (t, f)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.map(f)
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([k, v]) =>  [k, f(v, k)]))
    default:
      return t
  }
}

function filter (t, f)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.filter(f)
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).filter(([k, v]) =>  f(v, k)))
    default:
      return t
  }
}

const input =
  {a: {b: 1, c: {a: 1, d: {}, e: {f: {}}}}, b: {}}

console.log(removeEmpties(input))
```

```js
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
      "a": 1
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to include `null` or `undefined` -

```js
function nonEmpty (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      // ...
    case Object:
      // ...
    default:
      return t != null && !== empty // <- 
  }
}
```

If you don't want to include empty strings, numbers, or false booleans -

```js
function nonEmpty (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      // ...
    case Object:
      // ...
    case String:
      return t.length > 0  // <-
    case Number:
      return t != 0        // <-
    case Boolean:
      return !t            // <-
    default:
      // ...
  }
}
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960623/633183) for a related approach and explanation of inductive reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it.

```js
const isNullOrEmpty = (obj) =>
  obj == null || (Object (obj) === obj && Object .keys (obj) .length == 0)

const clearNullEmpties = (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => {
        const val = clearNullEmpties (v) 
        return isNullOrEmpty (val) ? [] : [[k, val]]
      }))
    : obj
 
const object = {a: {b: 1, c: {a: 1, d: {}, e: {f: {}}}}, b: {}}

console .log (clearNullEmpties (object))
```

We use `Object.entries` to break our object into key-value pairs, and then using `flatMap`, we combine a filtering and mapping operation on those pairs, recursively running the values through this function and keeping those ones that do not return an empty value, using our helper `isNullOrEmpty`.  Then we recombine the results with `Object.fromEntries`.

If you need to handle arrays as well, that would take a little additional work, but shouldn't be hard.

Note that the above is a little more beginner-friendly than my personal preferred variant of this, which uses only expressions and no statements, and involves one more helper function:

```
const call = (fn, ...args)=>
  fn (...args)

const clearNullEmpties = (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => call (
        (val = clearNullEmpties (v)) => !isNullOrEmpty (val) ? [[k, val]] : []
      )))
    : obj
```

Comment: `call` has utility everywhere! i wonder if we will ever see a native syntax to support assignment expressions...

Comment: @Thankyou and you both did well job and I learned lot in just one question. not sure which one should i mark as right Answer... confused.

Comment: Choose whichever you like.  I don't chase reputation points, and I doubt that Thankyou does either.  I personally would choose the answer from Thankyou.  It's more flexible and more generic.  Mine has only the advantage of being shorter.

Comment: A humble bunch, we are :D I am only here to participate with other passionated coders. I have learned so much from helping others and discussing these fun programming puzzles with my peers.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
const clearNullEmpties = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {}

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, val], i) => {
    const isNotNull = val !== null
    const isObject = isNotNull && val.constructor === Object
    const isEmptyObj = isObject && Object.keys(val).length === 0

    /* call twice in case the result returned is iteslf an empty object,
    as with e in the Example Data */
    const result = (isObject && !isEmptyObj && clearNullEmpties(clearNullEmpties(val))) 
    
    if(isObject) {
      result && Object.assign(newObj, { [k]: result })
    } else if (isNotNull) {
      Object.assign(newObj, { [k]: (val) })
    }
  })

  return newObj
}


// Example Data
let object = {
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: {
            a: 1,
            d: null,
            e: {
              f: {} 
            }
        }
    },
    b: {}
}


let expectedResult = {
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: {
            a: 1,
        }
    }
}

console.log("result", clearNullEmpties(object))
console.log("expected", expectedResult)
```

Comment: If you change, say, `d` to `null`, it gets included in the output.  I think that's unwanted.

Comment: Then you might want to see my answer, or even better, the one from the always-brilliant Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've fixed it now.